# TouchesBegan does not work

Tags: ios, swift

In the last label `lblTryAgain` I want to return to another class named GameScene but the tap action does not enter to the function touchesBegan.
I am just following a tutorial to learn how to create games with SpriteKit if someone want to follow the tutorial or see the entire code is available in https://www.raywenderlich.com/87231/make-game-like-mega-jump-sprite-kit-swift-part-1

```swift
import SpriteKit

class EndGameScene: SKScene {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)

        // Stars
        let star = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Star")
        star.position = CGPoint(x: 25, y: self.size.height-30)
        addChild(star)

        let lblStars = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "ChalkboardSE-Bold")
        lblStars.fontSize = 30
        lblStars.fontColor = SKColor.white
        lblStars.position = CGPoint(x: 50, y: self.size.height-40)
        lblStars.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.left
        lblStars.text = String(format: "X %d", GameState.sharedInstance.stars)
        addChild(lblStars)

        // Score
        let lblScore = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "ChalkboardSE-Bold")
        lblScore.fontSize = 60
        lblScore.fontColor = SKColor.white
        lblScore.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: 300)
        lblScore.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.center
        lblScore.text = String(format: "%d", GameState.sharedInstance.score)
        addChild(lblScore)

        // High Score
        let lblHighScore = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "ChalkboardSE-Bold")
        lblHighScore.fontSize = 30
        lblHighScore.fontColor = SKColor.cyan
        lblHighScore.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: 150)
        lblHighScore.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.center
        lblHighScore.text = String(format: "High Score: %d", GameState.sharedInstance.highScore)
        addChild(lblHighScore)


        // Try again
        let lblTryAgain = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "ChalkboardSE-Bold")
        lblTryAgain.fontSize = 30
        lblTryAgain.fontColor = SKColor.white
        lblTryAgain.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: 50)
        lblTryAgain.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.center
        lblTryAgain.text = "Tap To Try Again"
        lblTryAgain.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        addChild(lblTryAgain)


    }

    func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        // Transition back to the Game
        let reveal = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
        let gameScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
        self.view!.presentScene(gameScene, transition: reveal)
    }

}
```

Comment: your method touches began declaration is wrong

Comment: `override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {`

Comment: are you working on swift 3 ?

Comment: Yes, is Swift 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`touchesBegan` is a override `func` which only works in `self.view`and it will not work in other UIs
try this

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    print("working")
}
```

Comment: `touchesBegan` is an instace method, not an overrided function. You can ovverride this method on your class to check if a new touch is detected in a view or window. And it's not limited to `self.view`..

Answer (score 1):

make sure  `isUserInteractionEnabled` is checked and the `print` statement may not work.  add or update `sceneDidLoad` and print `isUserInteractionEnabled`